# UWP - Get IMSI and IMEI

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I've seen many questions posted on trying to get the IMSI or IMEI on Windows Phone 8.1, many of which state that it's not possible. I would like to know whether this is still the case when it comes to Windows Phone 10 (UWP)?

Many thanks in advance!
Kind regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately on the Windows 10 Mobile only mobile operator apps and Windows Store apps given privileged access by mobile network operators have access to such data.

Please see below article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn391779.aspx